# Присоединительный характер меняет пунктуацию при вводных?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, запятые, вводные-слова

1. *Средство быстро, **а главное**, полностью смывается, что делает его абсолютно безопасным даже для мытья детской посуды* (мой пример).
2. *В результате сила электромагнитного поля приходящих сигналов, **а значит**, и сила приёма увеличивается во много раз* ([источник](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/726%E2%80%91210_vvodnye_slova__slovosochetaniya_i_predlozheniya.html)).
3. *Эта схема, **а следовательно**, и весь проект в целом нуждается в проверке* ([источник](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/726%E2%80%91210_vvodnye_slova__slovosochetaniya_i_predlozheniya.html)).

Если в данных примерах автор захочет придать второму однородному члену добавочный, присоединительный характер, то оформление будет по типу присоединительной конструкции?

1. *Средство быстро, **а главное полностью**, смывается, что делает его абсолютно безопасным даже для мытья детской посуды.*
2. *В результате сила электромагнитного поля приходящих сигналов, **а значит и сила приёма**, увеличивается во много раз.*
3. *Эта схема, **а следовательно и весь проект в целом**, нуждается в проверке.*

Comment: Василий, прошу прощения за комментарий не по теме; хотел попросить вас, если это возможно, уделить внимание обсуждению, развернувшемуся в комментариях к блогу нашего сайта: https://rus.meta.stackexchange.com/q/417/178412. Было бы прекрасно, если бы вы смогли подсказать, как можно увеличить популярность сайта, активность на нем и т. п. Буду рад продолжить обсуждение на Мете. Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, что вы сами расставили все точки над i. Всё правильно.

[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122)  4. Если вводное слово (сочетание) стоит в начале или в конце обособленного оборота (обособления, уточнения, пояснения, присоединения), то никаким знаком препинания от оборота оно не отделяется: А Пётр Петрович, по крайней мере по многим признакам, человек весьма почтенный (Дост.)

Answer (score 1):

**Сомнение вызывает союз А:** зачем он здесь?

В принципе предложение может иметь **три варианта:**

(1) В результате сила электромагнитного поля приходящих сигналов и, **значит**, сила приёма увеличивается во много раз.

(2) В результате сила электромагнитного поля приходящих сигналов, **а значит**, и сила приёма увеличивается во много раз

(3) В результате сила электромагнитного поля приходящих сигналов, **а значит и сила приёма**,  увеличивается во много раз.

Вариант (1) ― это однородные отношения, вариант (3) ― обособление (уточнение, пояснение, выделение и т.д.), а вариант (2) ― это что, тоже однородные отношения? **Вот здесь и непонятна роль союза А.**

**А ― противительный союз.** С его помощью сопоставляются или противопоставляются факты, которые различаются по какому-то признаку, но не являются взаимоисключающими, а сосуществуют. **Сопоставительное значение для этого союза является главным.** Может быть, поэтому союз А способствует **обособлению** второго однородного члена?

Исходя из всего сказанного, можно сделать вывод, что  вариант (2), возможно,  лишний, то есть при наличии союза А мы должны **обособлять всю конструкцию.**

**Хотелось бы услышать мнение сообщества по этой теме.**

Comment: Кроме противопоставления и сопоставления у союза «а» ещё есть одно важное значение: союз «а» присоединяет предложения или члены предложения со значением добавления чего-н. при последовательном изложении, пояснения, возражения, усиления, перехода к другой мысли. Я полагаю, в вашем предложении 2 он больше дифференцирует второй однородный член и усиливает отношения следствия, передаваемые  вводным словом «значит».

Comment: Спасибо, желательно, чтобы Вы указывали источник, которым пользуетесь при определении функций союза А. Наличие двух союзов в одной конструкции требует понимания их взаимосвязи. Но в любом случае три варианта оформления - это много, В Нацкорпусе по этой теме понять ничего нельзя: запятые ставятся как кому нравится.

Comment: С. И. Ожегов «Толковый словарь русского языка»

Comment: Функцию союза лучше изучать по грамматическим источникам, лично я пользуюсь вузовским учебником, недавно изданным. Там названо основное сопоставительное значение союза А. В тоже время для того, чтобы сопоставить, надо второй член выделить из ряда. Поэтому я считаю, что такие конструкции желательно обособлять.